# Cannot install Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS on a computer with Windows 10 UEFI

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I have an Asus GL552VW with Windows 10 UEFI on its SSD disk. I tried to install Ubuntu on the HDD, but when I chose “Install Ubuntu” the purple loading screen didn’t disappear. I tried installing from both CD and USB, and always have the same problem.

Comment: Have you secure boot from bios and turned off fast boot of Windows 10 ? Did a `grub` screen appear for you to select OS to run?

Answer (score 1):

When you get to the install menu you need to change the boot sequence a bit. With `Install Ubuntu` selected, press <kbd>e</kbd> and add `nomodeset` just after `splash`. Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> to continue booting. You should be able to install the system as you normally would.

Or, if given the option in the install menu, press <kbd>F6</kbd> and choose `nomodeset` from the dropdown menu.